# How to get Blimp Contact?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How can I get Blimp Contact in my GTA for PS 3 because the Blimp Contact is not available on the contact list and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What do you mean by Blimp Contact?

Comment: @Stevoisiak - There's a contact you can call to reserve/spawn the blimp at the nearest launch point. Kelvin - Your best bet would be to make sure PS3 even has the blimp, as there's a bit of content that wasn't released on older consoles but is on new consoles + PC.

Comment: @l3l_aze Exactly the context I needed. Was able to [post an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/406197/181240).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [GTA Wiki](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Atomic_Blimp), the blimp phone contact used to access the Atomic Blimp is only available to those who pre-ordered GTA V, have the [Special/Collectors Editions](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V/Editions#Editions_comparison), or are playing the Enhanced Edition on PS4/PS5/Xbox One/Xbox X/PC.

Since you are playing GTA V on PS3, you will only have access to the Atomic Blimp if you pre-ordered the game or are playing either the Special or Collector's Edition. See the [below table comparing the different versions](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V/Editions#Editions_comparison).

[image]